# How can I get this jquery function to work using a div in a different frame?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$('#notice').countDown({
    startNumber: 10,
    callBack: function(me) {
        $(me).text('Logging out now...').css('color','#090');
    }
});
```

Instead of using  on the page that the script is on I'd like to use  that lives in a different frame, specifically a frame named "header"

Any help or direction would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using...

```
$('#notice', parent.frames['header'].document)
```

Comment: Thanks...I'm wondering if ['header'] is the id or the name of the frame.